# Filter Item on Subitem category powerbi

Tags: powerbi, business-intelligence, ssas-tabular

I have been having trouble trying to filter on a dimension table that is larger than the fact table.

I am using Power BI for presentation and using an endpoint on an ssas tabular server, I am using direct query.
I am trying to filter on a tag that is sat on the subitem of an item which has a valid column that results to true/false. An example of the dataset could be like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/koLyu4ad/

```
The Resulting HTML displays sample Data
```

I want to dynamically filter on sub-item tags, so if I create a slicer with the tags, and you select tag-1, only item 1 and 2 will show, if you select tag 2, only item 2 and 3 will show.

Comment: jsfiddle for sample data!

Comment: If you can edit the SSAS model you could turn on two-way filtering on the relationship between the two tables.

Comment: @TDP Do you have a link?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/tabular-models/bi-directional-cross-filters-tabular-models-analysis-services?view=sql-analysis-services-2017